# Compact Sobolev Embedding

Tags: functional-analysis, soft-question, sobolev-spaces, online-resources

Let $\Omega \subseteq \mathbb R^d$ a bounded domain. My professor told me that there is a compact embedding $H_0^1(\Omega) \hookrightarrow L^2(\Omega)$. I am currently looking for some good sources for this theorem and its proof. So I would really appreciate some scripts or literature which deals with this embedding. Thank you in advance :)

Comment: See Evans book on PDEs. Chapter 5 section 7 on Rellich compactness theorem. See also the remark at the end of the theorem

Comment: Thanks, that's a nice source :) Nonetheless I would appreciate more sources!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @Siddhant suggest, Evans book is a good resources. Here I want to recommend Leoni's [book](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0821847686). It has more details in calculations and more lemmas.

Also, another good resources would be Adams [book](https://books.google.com/books/about/Sobolev_Spaces.html?id=R5A65Koh-EoC&source=kp_cover). It gives more information for higher order sobolev space and also deal with irregular domains.

Those two, plus Evans, should be very enough.

Comment: Thank you, nice sources :)